# How to center text output by drawString in Java

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to center the text output from drawString on the X coordinate in a program. I am trying to get the width of my window and devide by two to get the center but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
package net.minecraft.src;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;

public class GuiIngame extends Gui
{
//lots of other code here
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
String xCords = nf.format(mc.thePlayer.posX);
String yCords = nf.format(mc.thePlayer.posY);
String zCords = nf.format(mc.thePlayer.posZ);
drawString(fontrenderer, (new StringBuilder()).append("X: ").append(xCords).toString(), 20, 2, 0xe0e0e0);
drawString(fontrenderer, (new StringBuilder()).append("Y: ").append(xCords).toString(), 40, 2, 0xe0e0e0);
drawString(fontrenderer, (new StringBuilder()).append("Z: ").append(xCords).toString(), 60, 2, 0xe0e0e0);
}
```

It only needs to be centered on the x axis.

Comment: First example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you draw 3 times xCords? Any reason for not using String.format? Why do you create StringBuilder when you can use the '+' sign? What is the hierarchy of Gui?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet I drew xCords 3 times for testing my code. I also am slightly new at Java. This code was taken from other code already written.

Comment: @Richante Correct me if I am wrong but isn't that to get the length of the text, not the center of the window?

Comment: I am just throwing some improvements to your code (in terms of readability, mainly). Now, my question still remains "What is the type hierarchy of Gui?".  what is the type of fontrenderer? We can't guess the context of your code, so you need to provide it in order  for us to help you

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a integer that I didn't know of that did the job. My final code to display each line is:

```
drawCenteredString(fontrenderer, (new StringBuilder()).append("X: ").append(xCords).toString(), mc.displayWidth / 4, 2, 0xe0e0e0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
String coord_text = new StringBuilder()).append("X: ").append(xCords).toString();
gui.drawString(fontrenderer, coord_text, gui.width/2 - fontrenderer.getStringWidth(coord_text)/2, 2, 0xe0e0e0);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific function for doing this, i beleive it is called drawCenterString